# Why is the slope-intercept form of the equation of a line often written $y=mx+b$? Why $m$ instead of $a$?

Tags: soft-question, notation

After a quick google search, I read something about [Conway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Horton_Conway) suggesting the $m$ having to do with "modulus" ...

This seems odd to me, but perhaps there is some mathematical reason? I've heard of the uses of the word modulus [in real/complex analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value) and [in number theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation), but neither seem applicable here.

Comment: See http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/52477.html

Comment: Or you may think of "$m$" as implying "multiple". Then the equation $y = mx + b$ may be read as "$y$ is some multiple of $x$ plus $b$". You may recall that in number theory we write "$y = qx + r$, for "$q$" hints "quotient" and "$r$" hints "remainder".

Comment: See also Jeff Miller's "Earliest Uses of Symbols from Geometry" http://jeff560.tripod.com/geometry.html

Comment: I've seen a book or two claiming m comes from a french word related to "mount", but maybe that's not backed up by anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this page](http://jeff560.tripod.com/geometry.html) independent of [vuur](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1070269/why-is-the-slope-intercept-form-of-the-equation-of-a-line-often-written-y-mxb#comment2178441_1070269) and found this question, so I might as well answer it. Specifically,

> The earliest known use of m for slope appears in Vincenzo Riccati’s memoir *De methodo Hermanni ad locos geometricos resolvendos*, which is chapter XII of the first part of his book *Vincentii Riccati Opusculorum ad res Physica, & Mathematicas pertinentium* (1757):
>
> > Propositio prima. Aequationes primi gradus construere. Ut Hermanni methodo utamor, danda est aequationi hujusmodi forma y = mx + n, quod semper fieri posse certum est. (p. 151)

The Latin simply states that this is the form of a linear equation, and Riccati does not remark upon the use of $m$.

Interestingly enough, *Traite Elementaire D'Arithmetique, Al'Usage De L'Ecole Centrale des Quatre-Nations: Par S.F. LaCroix, Dix-Huitieme Edition*, published in 1830 *does* use $a$ instead of $m$ (although it obviously was not written by Riccati).

[As DavidK pointed out](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1070269/why-is-the-slope-intercept-form-of-the-equation-of-a-line-often-written-y-mxb/1423108#comment2899207_1423108), George Salmon also used $a$ in his work in the 19th century. I had omitted that from my original answer because he used a different form,
$$\frac{x}{a}+\frac{y}{b}=1$$
but it is still a relevant usage.

Comment: [The page linked above](http://jeff560.tripod.com/geometry.html) also cites the equation $(x/a) + (y/b) = 1$ as one form of the equation for a line. If you convert this equation to the slope-intercept form, the constant term is $b$, but the coefficient of $x$ is $-\frac ba$, not $a$. When a symbol other than $a$, such as $m$, is the coefficient of $x$ in the slope-intercept form, it is possible to write $(x/a) + (y/b) = 1$ by expressing $a$ in terms of $m$ (provided that $m$ is not zero).

Comment: @DavidK Makes sense. I had taken the question to refer to equations just written in the form $y=f(x)$, so I skipped over that.

Comment: @DavidK I edited that in. Thanks for that.